# nginx cache not getting build, and served when upstream is down

Tags: caching, nginx

Following is my nginx conf. I'm trying to run a basic static web application and server through nginx. While the web application is down, I want nginx to server the cached content. But as soon as I turn off my web application nginx throws error page.

Following is my nginx.conf

```
user  D staff;
worker_processes  1;
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
  include       mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  sendfile        on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;
  proxy_cache_path  /data/cache/ levels=1:2 keys_zone=default:8m max_size=1000m inactive=30d;
  proxy_temp_path   /data/tmp/;

  server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {

      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;

      proxy_cache default;

    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      root   html;
    }
  }
}
```

Also I'm not able to see the cache getting build inside the cache folder /date/cache/.

Current version of nginx is 1.8.0

Answer (score 0):

The app was setting the Cache-Control:"max-age=0, private, must-revalidate" and hence nginx was not considering the responses for cache. I have added a config to ignore Cache-Control, hence it started working.

```
proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
```